# Async and SwiftUi Views

Tags: swiftui, mvvm, async-await

Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
.navigationDestination(for: User.self, destination: { user in
                let chat = Task { try await viewModel.createChat(currentUserId: currentUser!.id, opposingUserId: user.id) }
                if chat == ChatModel.self {
                    ChatView(chat: chat)
                } else {
                    Text("Fehler: Chat konnte nicht erstellt oder gefunden werden")
                }
                
            })
```

What I'm basically trying to do is to assign the returnValue of my async func createChat (which should return a ChatModel if it doesn't throw an error) to my chat-contstant. Then I'm trying to find out if the Task returned a ChatModel or an Error. If it returned a ChatModel the ChatView should be initialized with the chatModel otherwise a Text should be displayed for now.

***Edit***: It should  work with this:

And does this work with such a structure:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
                        NavigationLink(value: user) {
                            VStack {
                                UserCell(user: user, buttonText: "startChat")
                                
                                Divider()
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical, 4)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: User.self, destination: { user in
            let chat = Task { try await viewModel.createChat(currentUserId: currentUser!.id, opposingUserId: user.id) }
            if chat == ChatModel.self {
                ChatView(chat: chat)
            } else {
                Text("Fehler: Chat cannot be found or created")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should change the design. `ChatView` should take the `currentUser` and `user`, and do the async operation in a `.task { ... }`. And what do you want to display when the async operation is ongoing?

Comment: Yup it's `.task {}` in SwiftUI not `Task {}`

Comment: @Sweeper A loading text should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

the `destination` for this form of SwiftUI's navigation should really be as straightforward a `View` as you can make it.

I would consider having an outer chat view that accepts a `User` object. It could have a @State that represents the loading state of your chat; you will update the state as a result of your `Task`, and choose which subview depending on the loading state. For example (this is very rough code):

```swift
enum LoadingState {
  case loading
  case loaded(ChatModel)
  case error(Error)
}

struct ChatView: View {
  var user: User
  @State private var loadingState: LoadingState = .loading

  var body: some View {
    Group { // because you can't attach modifiers directly to a switch
      switch loadingState {
      case .loading:
        Text("Loading...")
      case .loaded(let chatModel):
        ChatModelView(model: chatModel)
      case .error(let error):
        Text(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
    .task {
      do {
        let chatModel = try await viewModel.createChat(currentUserId: currentUser!.id, opposingUserId: user.id)
        loadingState = .loaded(chatModel)
      catch {
        loadingState = .error(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then the setup in the parent view would be

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: User.self) { user in ChatView(user: user) }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to create this example. Unfortunately I get an error in the line where the landing text should be handled (Text("Loading...")). The error is: No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'

Comment: And does your proposed architecture work with the "Edit"-Section in  my question?